# Alexa, get skill from LaunchRequest Intent

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I got 3 skills in my account, eg `SkillA`, `SkillB` and `SkillC`.

I am using an endpoint url to listen to these skills, and my server is common for all the 3 skills. So if I try to invoke a skill by saying `open SkillA` it invokes `LaunchRequest`. Same is the case with other 2 skills.

So how would I be able to know which Skill's `LaunchRequest` was invoked.

My server is ruby with Ralyxa Gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every skill there is a unique Skill ID known as `applicationId`. Making use of this `applicationId` from the request JSON you can easily determine from which skill the request came in.

You can find this `applicationId` under `application` object in every request from Alexa to your backend.

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "session": {
        "new": true,
        "sessionId": "amzn1.echo-api.session.xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx",
        "application": {
            "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
        },
        "user": {
            "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    },

...
```

You can also view the Skill ID from Alexa developers console where your Alexa Skills are listed.

[image]